# refer a custom record field in HTML template

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, email-templates, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to create a HTML template to email a gift card, value of which depends on the amount customer spends. So, I wanted to show the value of the gift card on the email they receive.

I've created a custom record field in the marketing campaign event sub-list to store the value and use in a HTML template but when I use its Id to refer it in the template it's not showing up anything.

```
${campaignEvent.custrecord_amountearned}
```

Comment: Are you using the advanced HTML/PDF templates?

Comment: No, its a marketing template, in which I've uploaded my own HTML file.

Comment: What if you tried `${record.campaignEvent.custrecord_amountearned}`

Comment: Am I replacing the "record" with actual record that it is on? If it is so, I've already tried `{campaign.campaignEvent.custrecord_amountearned}` which didn't work too.

Comment: At least in the Advanced/HTML templates, "record" is how I believe fields are normally accessed, depending on the template. I've used `{record.entity.phone}` to pull a customer's phone number when the original record was the sales order.

Comment: I actually have an other field "promcode" that I'm referring as `${campaignEvent.couponCode}` which is working fine but I don't know why this isn't working even though both are on the same campaign event